# Is it possible to use html to style a div i cannot directly access the code of?

Tags: html, css, content-management-system

I am using a cms system that allows me to write html in a source box, a bit like wordpress. There is a div currently showing on my site that i cannot directly access the html or css of so i am un-able to get rid of it. Is it possible for me to write something with html that will allow me to hide this div ?

Comment: javascript yes, html don't think soo

Comment: add style blog inside your html and hide the div using display:none

Comment: I would say you can't. HTML defines the content of a webpage, not its styling. You have to solve this by CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your below line:

> .......css of so i am un-able to get rid of it.

lets say `id` of div is `div1` then on the main HTML page which you have access to, add below lines :

```
<style>
  #div1 { display:none }
</style>
```

Not very sure on this but logically this should work!!

Comment: Thank you, i feel a little silly due to the simplicity of the solution  but you have helped me out massively!

Comment: *silly..?* mate, if i judge myself on that standard, i justify my screen name completely...cheers!! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `document.addEventListener` inside a `<script>` tag to change the properties of the interested `<div>` block after the page is completed loaded.